# Android Facebook logout is not working

Tags: android, facebook, logout, facebook-android-sdk

Now i am working with android Facebook integration.But logout is not working on this.without logout from my browser in phone i can't logout from my application.why this happening?.How can we avoid this

Answer (score 0):

There are two independent things going on here:
 1) whether your user has authenticated your app (with permissions) to Facebook and
2) whether your user is logged in to Facebook.

Authentication is required the first time your user uses your app and lasts until the user explicitly de-authenticates (e.g. through the Facebook web Account Settings -> Apps -> App Settings).

Log in may be required each time your user starts your app. But if you use the default SDK authorize(), that tries to do a Single Sign On (SSO), where if the Facebook app is logged in, your app is automatically logged in and uses the existing access token.

If you are using SSO, when you do a logout, that has no effect, as a real logout would have to log out the Facebook app - which the user might not like!

You can get around this behavior by doing an authorize of the form

```
authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
```

which avoids SSO and forces a dialog login. Of course, that then forces your user to login each time you start your app - unless you save the login details / access token under the 
covers (which is what the SDK does - check the source).

**EDITED:**

> ```
>  m_facebook.authorize(FacebookActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
>             new LoginDialogListener());
>
>  class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener
> {
>     public void onComplete(Bundle p_values)
>     {
>         saveCredentials(m_facebook);
>         if (m_messageToPost != null)
>         {
>             postToWall(m_messageToPost);
>         }
>     }       
>     public void onFacebookError(FacebookError p_error)
>     {
>         finish();
>     }       
>     public void onError(DialogError p_error)
>     {
>         finish();
>     }       
>     public void onCancel()
>     {
>         finish();
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: what is the "FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH",all other parameters are replaced,but no idea of FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH this help me.

Comment: My point is that, if you are using SSO, isSessionValid does not tell you anything about the underlying login status. Why not try using the FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH form of authorize and see what happens?

Comment: facebook.authorize(
     this,
     new String[] { "read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access,friends_about_me,user_birthday" },-1,
     new DialogListener() {
      public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
       Facebook.access_token = facebook.getAccessToken();
       getMyInfo();

      }

Comment: where i want to change .-1 is there instead of FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH .what changes have to be done in above code?

Comment: You can check my updated answer .I have shown where to keep the `FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH`